# UIImageView act as button

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a UIImageView that I want to receieve an action. I want it to act like a button. It will not have an image set so it will be invisible, then when tapped i want it to change to an image.

I know that IBActions do not work on a UIImageView. How could I achieve this?

Comment: invisible or transparent?

Comment: use tap gestures and change the image on imageview.

Comment: if you use custom button then is there any problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not just use a UIButton and set an image to it and/or make it visible and enabled or invisible and disabled like normal developers like to do?

If your UIButton has no image in it, I think you can still tap the area and then you can assign an image to it through "`setImage:forState:`".

Comment: Thank u for replay . i have change my mind after your replay i have use the UIButton and set Image in custom option. Thank

Answer (score 1):

this code might be your solution. plz try out.

```
UIButton b=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [b setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b addTarget:own action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [own.view addSubview:b];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIButton, set the button's type to "custom" in Interface Builder and choose your image as the background image of the button. Assign an IBAction to the button and make it invisible from your action.

Or,

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage 
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a UIImageView you would have to set `myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` and then add a gesture recognizer to it:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
myGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
myGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:myGestureRecognizer];
```

Otherwise I would suggest using a UIButton together with a background image.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Add this to your view controller:

func makeButton(imageView: UIImageView, onPressed: Selector) {

```
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let gr = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    gr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    gr.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    gr.addTarget(self, action: onPressed)
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gr)
}
```

and call it using:

```
makeButton(myImageView, onPressed: self.buttonPressed)
```